# GSON TypeAdapter that delegates the super class to default parser

Tags: java, json, gson

Imagine the following class hierarchy:

**Mother of all types**

```
public abstract class AbstractSuperType {
   private String id;
   private long time;
}
```

**Base user type**

```
public abstract class AbstractUserItem extends AbstractSuperType {
    private String uid;
    private String name;
}
```

**Sepacial User data type 1**

```
public class UserItemType1 extends AbstractUserItem {
    private EnumType type;
    private String typeValue;
}
```

And this example JSON to go with it:

```
{
  "id":"12345aabc",
  "time":123456789012,
  "uid":"cca112233",
  "name":"Bob Jones"
  "a":2,
  "b":3.12345,
  "c": { some_special_value }
}
```

The `EnumType` field isn't declared inside the JSON, but rather depends on what keys are present. The `typeValue` field is also populated based on the parsed`EnumType` (For example if keys *a* and *b* exist in the JSON, it's a `Type 1` data and it's value is in key *c*.

I'm having some trouble parsing this: I can parse the `EnumType` and the `typeValue` fine, but I'd rather not hand-parse the rest of the hierarchy because

1. The default parser does it just fine
2. If the base objects change, I'll have to update this code as well

My Question is: **Is there a way to delegate the first 2 tiers to the default parser, and then take over and perform my custom parsing?**

Thanks

Comment: The answer is basically: "No". If the two superclasses weren't abstract you'd have the option of using Gson inside your deserializer via the `JsonDeserializationContext` and have them deserialized to an instance of the direct superclass. If this is something you really need you should perhaps think about composition over inheritance. The decorator pattern, for example, may be useful.

Comment: Thanks. I could always have **all** those values in the object and move the determining logic to the _getter_ and _setter_ methods.